# How to prove/disprove proof on limits (delta-epsilon)

Tags: proof-writing

Prove or disprove: $$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta>0, \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^+, |x - y| > \delta ⇒ |x + y| > \epsilon $$

I've been trying this for some time now but can't seem to get anywhere. I tried proving it then disproving it. Need help figuring out what to choose for the values of $\epsilon$, $x$, $y$ if disproving or of $\delta$ if proving. Also not sure if i'm following the right steps, some clarity would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $\delta=\epsilon$, if $|x-y|>\delta$ then $|x+y|>|x-y|>\delta=\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

If $y<x$ then $|x+y|=x+y\geq x-y+y\geq|x-y|$ so if $|x-y|>\delta$ then $|x+y|>\delta$. If $x<y$ then $x+y\geq y-x+x\geq|x-y|$.

Comment: I think there is a typo here somewhere. You say that $x + y = x - y + y$, which is generally false.

Comment: @Johanna The = sign should have been $\geq$. The method still works.

Comment: That's what I thought :)